# Как сделать запрос на удаление?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp

Подскажите, как удалить определенные строки в базе данных, если они просрочились на 1 день.

```
public string value { get; set; } 

public DateTime date { get; set; }
```

вот такая структура, использую LINQ. Нужно если дата просрочилась на 1 день от текущего времени, то ее удалить. Спасибо

Comment: Хорошо бы указать (в метках) какую именно версию EF используете (EF 6 или EF Core). И вряд ли вы используете старый добрый ASP, наверно все же ASP.NET (хотя вряд ли вообще это имеет отношение к вопросу по ef linq).

Comment: В чем суть вопроса? Вроде это не сложно делается и в любом туториале написано как удалять сущности. Другой вопрос, если вы не хотите перед удалением загружать эти сущности на клиенте... Но почему тогда клиент должен служить триггером для такой задачи?